# Why cookies are not receive in the request headers

Tags: cookies, nestjs, request-headers

The thing i want to mention is that i don't want to use any external pacakge for get and set cookie 
my cookies are set in the browser as below code

```
@Post('/set-cookies')
     checkUserType(@Body() secret: secretEntity, @Response() res, @Request() req) {
         res.header('Set-Cookie', ["setFromServer=1;Max-Age=3600;", "jscantsee=1; Max-Age=3600; path=/; httponly;"]);
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST, OPTIONS')
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept')
         res.send()
        // return this.SecretService.checkUserType(secret);
     };
```

**But it's not receive in the other request URL's request headers as I shown in this below image. it's only present in the '/set-cookie' post method and not any other url
what is the issue of not getting the cookie in all request headers?? so how do i get the cookies**

[image]

what i'm missing heer? plz help

Answer (score 0):

I have to add `withCredential:true`  in other methods I need to add `withCredential:true` in all the methods where i want to use cookies